# How to write in a text file by calling php script via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, text, execute

I am beginner in php. I uploaded a text file on a server and I want to write some information within this file using php. The code is working when I run it using XAMPP locally.

First I call the script using ajax (index.html):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'register.php',
    success: function (data) {
        // this is executed when ajax call finished well
        window.location = "general.html";
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // executed if something went wrong during call
        if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
    }
});
```

Then I write some information using a php script:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("user_information.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt1 = file_get_contents("user_information.txt");
$ip = get_client_ip_server();
$txt2 = $_COOKIE["userName"] ."\t" .$_COOKIE["userEmail"]." \t".$ip. "\r\n";
$txt3 = $txt1 . $txt2;
fwrite($myfile, $txt3);
fclose($myfile);

header( "HTTP/1.0 302 Found" );
header( "Status: 302" ); # this is for chrome compliance
header( "Location: general.html");

die();
// Function to get the client ip address
function get_client_ip_server() {
$ipaddress = '';
      if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress =getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
}
?>
```

The problem is that the text file remains blank on the server. I think that the php script is even not executed. I gave the authorization to write to the php file and to the text file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try to use the Chrome `Developer Tools -> Network` and check if the request is correcly sent and returns something. This way you can find out if your PHP script is either NOT called or contains errors.

Comment: Try using the full path to the file.

Comment: You should take a look to the error_log file, you can find the location of that file in the php.ini file(error_log = ...)

Comment: @ponciste I checked in Developer Tools -> Network but nothing is related to the php script. And where is the php.ini? on the server? And why does it work with XAMPP?

Comment: have you opened the developer tools before sending the request? That's weird, it should provide you a list of all the request that are sent from the page, including yours. Maybe the JS file is not called at all or is not running? Try to also check the tab `Console` to see if you have javascript errors in there

Comment: @ponciste Yes I did open it before. And there is no javascript errors. The javascript code is working because my page is redirected due to the line "window.location = "general.html";". I am not sure if I understand how ajax works. Is it sufficient to write "url: script.php" to execute a php script?

Comment: You should be getting an error for `$ip` I think as the function is declared after the function call this doesn't make sense, check the response of this page or try to run this script manually in your browser, you should get a `PHP` error

Comment: @GHOST93 The console log the following line: GET XHR http://path.../register.php
Normally you can declare the function after the call. I mean it's working with XAMPP so..

Comment: I am not telling about your `url:` part i am talking about your php script sir, in which `$ip = get_client_ip_server();` right, but the function is declared below the call and as PHP is interpreted not compiled you should be getting a Fatal Error

Comment: You say that the code runs localy ? If so, maybe your remote host dont allow this ?

Comment: @Mathieu Yes the code works when I use XAMPP. But when I upload it on the server everything works correctly except the editing of the text file. Yes it should be a problem with authorizations but nothing appears in the console log of the network that says that there is a problem.

Comment: Try to create a single php file on your remote host with only php functions like fopen() for testing purpose. Maybe your host dont allow php scripts to create or modify files, and maybe they disabled error reporting. It's common on free hosting services etc...

Comment: @Mathieu It's really weird. Even if I make a very simple php file: echo "<h1 style='color:red'>TEST TO CHECK</h1>"; Nothing display. I think that the php script is even not executed

Comment: I just copied your code here, and besides the fact your IP function is not getting the IP properly, it generates a file with contents inside.
Why did you use your PHP Location: general.html and on your ajax:success you reload it to general.html as well?

Comment: @HelioGabrenha thank you for your help. The IT guy explained me that the server I am using cannot run PHP. I feel stupid now :). I just have to ask for another server.